# Guardar varias variables en .txt con Python

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de facturación y cuando quiero guardar los datos en un `.txt`, estos no se guardan.

```
from io import open
from datetime import date
import random

fecha = date.today()
numero = random.randrange(1, 1000)
iva = 0.21

print(":::::::: Facturación ::::::::\n")

cliente = input("Cliente: ")
servicio = input("Servicio: ")
precio = int(input("Precio: $"))

subtotal = precio * iva
total = precio + subtotal

craer_factura = open(str(fecha)+str(numero)+".txt", "w")
craer_factura.write('''
"Factura #"+numero
"-------------------"
"Cliente: "+cliente
"Servicio: "+servicio
"-------------------"
"Valor: $"+precio
"IVA 21%: $"+subtotal
"-------------------"
"Total: $"total
''')

print("Total: $"+str(total))
```

No me arroja errores, pero me guarda en el `.txt` los datos tal cual están escritos y no me toma las variables.

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python no reemplaza automáticamente las variables dentro de la cadena. Si estás usando Python 3.6 o superior, puedes usar [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) para facilitar el asunto:

```
craer_factura = open(f'{fecha}{numero}.txt', "w")
craer_factura.write(f'''
Factura #{numero}
-------------------
Cliente: {cliente}
Servicio: {servicio}
-------------------
Valor: ${precio}
IVA 21%: ${subtotal}
-------------------
Total: ${total}
''')
```

Answer (score 3):

Tienes un problema como este:

```
variable = 1
cadena = """
El valor de variable es: + variable
"""

print(cadena)
El valor de variable es: + variable
```

Estas usando las triples comillas, que es la forma más sencilla para escribir cadenas multilínea, el problema, es que todo lo que está dentro de las triples comillas se evalúa como una única cadena, por lo que la concatenación que intentamos con `El valor de variable es: + variable` es inútil.

El otro problema que eventualmente podrías tener, si solucionas el anterior, es que el operador `+` funciona de distintas maneras  de acuerdo al tipo de datos. Por ejemplo:

```
variable = 1
cadena = "El valor de variable es:" + variable

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    cadena = "El valor de variable es:" + variable
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

El problema es simple, la concatenación (el `+`) solo funciona así si se trata de dos cadenas de caracteres, pero `variable` es un entero.

Una forma óptima es el uso de [`F-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) que ya te han comentado, válido para las versiones 3.6 o superiores, en versiones anteriores y superiores puedes hacer algo parecido, mediante el método `format()`:

```
variable = 1
cadena = "El valor de variable es: {0}" 

print(cadena.format(variable))
El valor de variable es: 1
```

Tomado tu caso, sería algo así:

```
craer_factura.write('''
Factura  # {0}
-------------------
Cliente:   {1}
Servicio:  {2}
-------------------
Valor:   $ {3}
IVA 21%: $ {4}
-------------------
Total:   $ {5}
'''.format(numero, cliente, servicio, precio, subtotal, total))
```